# Adding a sine generated audio track to a video stream with ffmepg

Tags: video, ffmpeg, audio

I'm generating an MPEG transport stream from a PNG file with `ffmpeg` succesfully with the following command:

```
ffmpeg -re -loop 1 -i smpte-color-bars-1080p.png -r 25 -vcodec libx264 -tune zerolatency -f mpegts udp://0.0.0.0:1234
```

I'd like to add an audio track to this usingthe sine function but am falling at the first hurdle.

I've tried:

```
ffmpeg -re -loop 1 -i smpte-color-bars-1080p.png -r 25 -vcodec libx264 -tune zerolatency -i sine=frequency=1000 -f mpegts udp://0.0.0.0:1234
```

and get the error:

```
Unknown decoder 'libx264'
```

Which implies that my arguments order is wrong.

So I then tried:

```
ffmpeg -re -loop 1 -i sine=frequency=1000 -i smpte-color-bars-1080p.png -r 25 -vcodec libx264 -tune zerolatency -f mpegts udp://0.0.0.0:1234
```

and get the error:

```
sine=frequency=1000: No such file or directory
```

What is the correct syntax for adding a sine generated audio in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sine` is a source *filter*, so the input format needs to be set as a filter using `-f lavfi`.

Use

```
ffmpeg -re -loop 1 -i smpte-color-bars-1080p.png -re -f lavfi -i sine=frequency=1000 -r 25 -vcodec libx264 -tune zerolatency -acodec aac -f mpegts udp://0.0.0.0:1234
```